# How do I set variable to the email column in $result?

Tags: php, mysql

I´m very new to PHP. Im trying to send username and email as $_SESSION to index.php.
I have tried resetting the pointer with mysql_data_seek($result,0);
and then use mysql_fetch...
Thanks in advance for your help.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username' and password='".md5($password)."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysql_error());
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($rows==1){

        $_SESSION['email'] ="emailcolumn in $result"; //<---- How to set this?
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header("Location: index.php"); // Redirect user to index.php
        }else{
```

Comment: at the beginig at session_start()

Comment: You are also mixing the APIs

Comment: **Never store passwords hashed by md5!** PHP provides [`password_hash()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them. If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure you [**don't escape passwords**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/5914775) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so changes the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Answer (score 7):

```
$result= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); //make the result an associative array
 $_SESSION['email'] = $result['email_column']; <--This is how we extract value from an associative array
```

Make sure you start the session at the top of your script (`session_start()`)
Thanks to @Mayank for pointing this out

Answer (score 0):

Put `session_start()` at the first line of the code and than set session like:

```
$_SESSION['email']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` to get data

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username' and password='".md5($password)."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($rows==1){

    $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $_SESSION['email'] = $data['your_column_name']; 

    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    header("Location: index.php"); // Redirect user to index.php
    }else{
```